# LINQ query for setting the value in collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the sum of `ProposalNumber` using below LINQ query

```
(from item in context.Target.Transaction
where item.Month >= detailsDaily.Month && item.Month <= parameter.Month
select item.ProposalNumber).Sum();
```

Now I want to set the value `ProposalNumber` to 0 between these above month as I used for select. Please suggest what should be LINQ query for that?

Comment: LINQ is **NOT** for updating data. If you have a set of results you want to update, then you should loop through them and update the property that you want to change... of course you need to make sure you have a reference to the original, and not a copy of the object you are trying to modify

Comment: @musefan,  I was asking something, that is mentioned in below answer. Is below query not LINQ?

Comment: Well, the bit where you *query* the data is... but the `ForEach` is not part of LINQ. It's just a method for `List<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have list of data as below:

```
var data = context.Target.Transaction
    .Where(m => m.Month >= detailsDaily.Month 
        && m.Month <= parameter.Month)
    .ToList();
```

Then you can find Sum like:

```
var sum = data.Sum(m => m.ProposalNumber);
```

And you can set `ProposalNumber` to 0 like:

```
data.ForEach(m => m.ProposalNumber = 0);
```

**Note:** If you are using Entity Framework (as I suppose you do) this can be expensive operation to load all data if you have too many rows. If you do not have a lot of data and you choose this way to update your data, then you have to call `context.SaveChanges()` for changes to take place after setting values. You also should make sure that `context.Configurations.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is set to true. I recommend using [Raw SQL queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) in such scenarios rather than this option.